# KVC compliant updates to NSMutableArray holding NSDictionary’s

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

My problem lies with updating an NSMutableArray which holds a varying number of NSDictionary’s. Each NSDictionary has 6 keys which are retrieved from a database depending on which record the user has selected in a table view. The array is linked to an NSArrayController which allows the user to select a dictionary and view the contents.

If the number[count] of dictionaries changes, the arrayController updates the view; no problem. However is the count of dictionaries is the same between selections in the table view, the arrayController does not update the view, but the model does update.

The arrayController is bound in IB to the model array which is updated whenever the selection changes in the table view.

Using:

```
[self.selectedJobNotes addObject:[self.jobNotes objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Which is not KVC compliant.

However using(which I believe to be KVC compliant):

```
[[self.selectedJobNotes objectAtIndex:noteCount] setValue:[[self.jobNotes objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@“Content"] forKeyPath:@"Content"];
```

does not work either.

Is there any way to tell the ArrayController this is a new array/has fresh content, so reload.

```
[self.jobNotesArrayController fetch:self.a2gDataObject.selectedJobNotes];
```

Doesn’t seem to work either??!

Answer (score 1):

Best way to solve this is to implement (and use) indexed accessors. In your case they'd look like

```
- (void)insertObject:(NSDictionary *)dict inSelectedJobNotesAtIndex:(NSUInteger) index {
    [self.selectedJobNotes addObject:[self.jobNotes objectAtIndex:index]];
}


- (void)insertSelectedJobNotes:(NSArray *)notesArray atIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexSet {
    [self.selectedJobNotes insertObjects:notesArray atIndexes:indexSet];
}
```

See KVC Programming Guide: [Mutable Indexed Accessors](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-SW4) and [Ensuring KVC Compliance](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002172).

You could also wrap your updates in `willChange/didChange ValueForKey:`, but implementing indexed accessors solves it once and for all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will give it a go.
In the mean time, just de-refferenced the array, then made a new one.
  selectedJobNotes = nil;

Clumsy and probably the wrong way to do it, but it worked short term.
I will try to implement these methods.
I think I did try the willChange/didChange but they didn’t work. Probably not correctly implemented.

Comment: Implemented these methods but I still have to destroy and recreated the array to get the desired result. Probably still doing it better than before.